# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. >

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Good afternoon Devs, I'll be honest.

My knowledge about Android Studio is almost basic.

I'll give you context:
A friend who is a Christian has told me that he has bought an online radio project, which consists of a Laravel system to manage the radios and 3 projects in Android Studio with Java.

When opening the project in Android Studio, it generates the error that I will leave below in this text.

I have already configured the One Signal AP ID, according to the person who sold you the complete radio system says that you just have to do that and generate the aab.

I would like your guidance please or if someone has already managed to find a solution to this problem, I have not been able to find a solution in the forums that I review.

I already updated Gradle and I also downgraded Gradle but it doesn't work either.

I leave the code below, I would appreciate any help possible.

Build file 'E:\Proyectos\Android\lapoderosa12\app\build.gradle' line: 9

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'GradleProjectPlugin'.
> > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: provide the ```app\build.gradle``` file

Comment: Did you get the solution?